# How to active when resize window

Tags: javascript, html

I want to active some function when my window goes down to certain size.

```
STANDARD_SIZE = 1760;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    if(window.innerWidth < STANDARD_SIZE ){
        $.post('/a', {size:'mobile'}, function(res){
            document.open();
            document.write(res);
            document.close();
        })}
    else{
        $.post('/a', {size:'window'}, function(res){
            document.open();
            document.write(res);
            document.close();
        })}});
```

Above is my code. Problem is when I resize my window, I need this code to active for last size, not the first size.

For example, I coded `alert('mobile')` and `alert('window')` to each if and else. When I resized width lower than 1760, it alert `window` 3 times and then alert `mobile`.

So I need that last 'mobile' to alert on first time, not last. Any idea?

---

And also is there more simple code than above code?

---

I am keep trying my code, above code does work when I resize above 1760.
But when I try to resize below 1760, It does not work.

---

(SOLVED) Above code does work. I was keep wondering why it work on `window`, but not `mobile` size. So I checked on server code(python). It was just word spelling error. Thanks for other answer below! Since there is know code error above, I will just leave for other who need help with resizing function.

Comment: When you go from `1800` to `1760` window resize will invoke and it must have to be window alert as per your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no event for "resize finished" you can set a timeout so your code won't run unless enough time was passed since the last resize event.

```js
STANDARD_SIZE = 1760;
var resizeTimer;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < STANDARD_SIZE) {
      alert("mobile");
      /*
      $.post('/a', {
        size: 'mobile'
      }, function(res) {
        document.open();
        document.write(res);
        document.close();
      })
      */
    } else {
      alert("window");
      /*
      $.post('/a', {
        size: 'window'
      }, function(res) {
        document.open();
        document.write(res);
        document.close();
      })
      */
    }
  }, 250);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict to multiple call

```js
STANDARD_SIZE = 1760;
var DEVICE = 'window';
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    if(window.innerWidth < STANDARD_SIZE && DEVICE != 'mobile' ){
        DEVICE = 'mobile';
        $.post('/a', {size:'mobile'}, function(res){
            document.open();
            document.write(res);
            document.close();
        })}
    else if(DEVICE != 'window'){
        DEVICE = 'window';
        $.post('/a', {size:'window'}, function(res){
            document.open();
            document.write(res);
            document.close();
        })}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to add new event listener for resize. Just do sample like below:

`<body onresize="resizeHandler()">`

then define your `resizeHandler()` function:

```
var STANDARD_SIZE = 1760;
var isWindow = true;
function resizeHandler() {
   if (window.innerWidth < STANDARD_SIZE && isWindow) {
       isWindow = false;
       alert('Mobile');
   } else if (!isWindow) {
       isWindow = true;
       alert('Window');
   }
}
```

The function handler above is just a trick to deal with your problem.